# HashRouter not working as expected after running npm run build

Tags: reactjs, react-router, routes, xampp

I am developing an app with reactjs

I ran npm run build and moved the content of the build folder to xampp server

The homepage works fine but other pages shows 404 Not Found error.

I changed my routing from BrowserHistory to HashRouter

But the problem persist.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { persistor, store } from "./noautharea/redux/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
   <Router>
     <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
     </PersistGate>
   </Router>
 </Provider>,
 document.getElementById("root")
);
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  const receptionist = "receptionist";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/manager/login" element={<Manager />} />
        <Route path="/receptionist/login" element={<Receptionist />} />
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Receptionist />} />
     </Routes>
   </div>
  )
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to changing App.js to this:

```
function App() {
  const receptionist = "receptionist";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/#/manager/login" element={<Manager />} />
        <Route path="/#/receptionist/login" element={<Receptionist />} />
        <Route path="/#/" exact element={<Receptionist />} />
     </Routes>
   </div>
  )
 }
```

I think the problem is HashRouter will render on '/#/' not '/'

Comment: did not work for me